# update nested object with (ES6) computed property name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my case, I'm using React.js and I would like to dynamically update the values in the `deployOptions` object.

For example -

initial state looks like:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
      deployOptions: {
        config: null,
        action: 'deploy',
        env: 'qa'
      }
    }
  }
```

Obviously this is not correct - but this is what I'm trying to achieve

```
configOptionChange(option) {

    // option -> { key: 'env', value: 'prod' }

    this.setState({
      [deployOptions.option.key]: option.value
    });
  }
```

so that my state would then be

```
{
    deployOptions: {
      config: null,
      action: 'deploy',
      env: 'prod' // only this changes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not especially pretty, but I think this is the best you can do with ES6:

```
configOptionChange({ key, value }) {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    deployOptions: {
      ...this.state.deployOptions,
      [key]: value
    }
  });
}
```

It's basically equivalent to your own `Object.assign` solution but using the ES6 spread (`...`) operator (and argument destructuring for good measure).

Here's a second option that isn't as clever but feels a little cleaner to me:

```
configOptionChange({ key, value }) {
  const { deployOptions: prevDeployOptions } = this.state;
  const deployOptions = { ...prevDeployOptions, [key]: value };
  this.setState({ ...this.state, deployOptions });
}
```

Comment: @Ben I've edited my answer to include an alternative solution. It's really just a matter of preference.

Comment: Oops, I just realized that my alternative solution would modify the original object (or rather its child object `deployOptions`), which is a big React no-no. I've edited it to avoid that.

Comment: Using this.state breaks immutability. If you wish to use this solution, make sure to use : 
this.setState(state => {...state,
    deployOptions: {
      ...state.deployOptions,
      [key]: value
    }});

Comment: @aneth101 "Using `this.state`" doesn't "break immutability." *Mutating* `this.state` breaks immutability. This code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just like these are `nested` objects, you can `nest` ES6 Computed Property Name like this:

```
[yourNestedObject]: {...yourNestedObject, [nestedObjectProperty]: value}
```

Here is an example function that will update an object's properties and the properties of nested objects. Where `prop` is the property to change, `value` is the value to assign, and `propObj` is the name of your `nested` object. I used `useState` hook for this.

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({
    prop1: '',
    prop2: '',
    nestedObj: {
        prop1: '',
        prop2: ''
    }
});
const updateObj = (prop, value, propObj=false) => {
    if (propObj) {
        setObj({...obj, [propObj]: {...obj[propObj], [prop]: value}})
    } else {
        setObj({...obj, [prop]: value})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do the trick - but if anyone has a better solution?

```
configOptionChange(option) {

    this.setState({
      deployOptions: Object.assign({}, this.state.deployOptions, {[option.key]: option.val})
    });

  }
```

Comment: Using this.state like this breaks immutability and you risk of getting change concurrency issues. This solution is to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to update the state of a component from a passed string of path properties:

```
handleChangeNested(event) {
    const target = event.target; //an <input /> tag
    let newState = { ...this.state };
    let valuePath = target.name.split('.'); //the input's name is the the keys of the state object like 'group1.input1'

    // Move down in the state object until we get to the 'bottom' property and change its value
    // If the object does not have the properties we create them on the fly
    valuePath.reduce((acc, key, index, path) => {
        if (index === path.length - 1) {
            acc[key] = target.value;
        }
    
        acc[key] = acc[key] || {};
        return acc[key];
    }, newState);

    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I know would be to use "immutable" library.

```
configOptionChange(option) {       
  // option -> { key: 'env', value: 'prod' }

  this.setState(state => setIn(state, ['deployOptions', option.key], option.value));
}
```